# What does an iOS profile have access to?

Tags: ios, security

I went to the website referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032162/#20546823) and by mistake I installed the profile they offered to me.

In one of the comments, someone mentioned:

> Do NOT use this site as it makes you install a Profile service which
>   can make your data accessible to the owner of the site

I don't know what an iOS profile can potentially steal from me. I did a factory reset. However, so far, what did they have access to?

- My passcode?
- My keyboard?
- My applications (I did not enter their password after installing the profile)?

In general, what maximum activities and information do they have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes! Glad you got it removed...

It really depends on the profile that you installed. Some profiles will enroll you into an MDM server (Mobile Device Management), where they can run reports on things like the serial number, UDID, MAC Address, apps installed, certificates installed, any restrictions (simple passcode, max failed attempts, etc.), and so on. Worst-case-scenario, they can [install apps remotely](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460), lock or even wipe your phone. Not to mention Activation Lock ([Find my iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365)).

Other profiles don't go that far but will change settings (such as setup an email account or proxy settings).

They can't see your passcode or have access to your keyboard. Although I believe someone could create and install a malicious app that looks harmless and asks for some info (passcode, iCloud account name/password, etc.). All the more reason not to monkey around with untrusted profiles and apps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If someone have my UDID and my passcode, can he/she break into my phone remotely?

Comment: Don't think so. Especially since you've reset the phone you're probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

The profile can only see your Unique Device Identifier. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your info. What can some one do with knowing my Unique Device Identifier?